# Parameterized SQL Columns?

Tags: sql-injection, parameterized

I have some code which utilizes parameterized queries to prevent against injection, but I also need to be able to dynamically construct the query regardless of the structure of the table.  What is the proper way to do this?

Here's an example, say I have a table with columns Name, Address, Telephone.  I have a web page where I run **Show Columns** and populate a select drop-down with them as options.

Next, I have a textbox called **Search**.  This textbox is used as the parameter.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
result = pquery('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE `' + escape(column) + '`=?', search);
```

I get an icky feeling from it though. The reason I'm using parameterized queries is to avoid using **escape**. Also, **escape** is likely not designed for escaping column names.

How can I make sure this works the way I intend?

**Edit:**
The reason I require dynamic queries is that the schema is user-configurable, and I will not be around to fix anything hard-coded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of passing the column names, just pass an identifier that you code will translate to a column name using a hardcoded table.  This means you don't need to worry about malicious data being passed, since all the data is either translated legally, or is known to be invalid.  Psudoish code:

```
@columns = qw/Name Address Telephone/;
if ($columns[$param]) {
  $query = "select * from contacts where $columns[$param] = ?";
} else {
  die "Invalid column!";
}

run_sql($query, $search);
```

Comment: Hard coding is not an option for me, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: My point is not to hardcode the column names, but not to pass them from the interface.  You can get the list of columns dynamically, and still use the same solution above.  Just don't make the column names part of the data passed -- that will protect you from any SQL injection.

Comment: +1 Yes, I like to say: let users enter data, but do not let users supply code.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to be confident in your escaping and validating routines.  I use my own SQL escape function that is overloaded for literals of different types.  Nowhere do I insert expressions (as opposed to quoted literal values) directly from user input.

Still, it can be done, I recommend a separate — and strict — function for validating the  column name.  Allow it to accept only a single identifier, something like

```
/^\w[\w\d_]*$/
```

You'll have to rely on assumptions you can make about your own column names.

Answer (score 0):

I use ADO.NET and the use of SQL Commands and SQLParameters to those commands which take care of the Escape problem.  So if you are in a Microsoft-tool environment as well, I can say that I use this very sucesfully to build dynamic SQL and yet protect my parameters

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Make the column based on the results of another query to a table that enumerates the possible schema values. In that second query you can hardcode the select to the column name that is used to define the schema. if no rows are returned then the entered column is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you enclose delimited identifiers in double quotes.  This means that:

```
SELECT * FROM "SomeTable" WHERE "SomeColumn" = ?
```

will select from a table called SomeTable with the shown capitalization (not a case-converted version of the name), and will apply a condition to a column called SomeColumn with the shown capitalization.

Of itself, that's not very helpful, but...if you can apply the escape() technique with double quotes to the names entered via your web form, then you can build up your query reasonably confidently.

Of course, you said you wanted to avoid using escape - and indeed you don't have to use it on the parameters where you provide the ? place-holders.  But where you are putting user-provided data into the query, you need to protect yourself from malicious people.

Different DBMS have different ways of providing delimited identifiers.  MS SQL Server, for instance, seems to use square brackets [SomeTable] instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Column names in some databases can contain spaces, which mean you'd have to quote the column name, but if your database contains no such columns, just run the column name through a regular expression or some sort of check before splicing into the SQL:

```
if ( $column !~ /^\w+$/ ) {
  die "Bad column name [$column]";
}
```